# Converting flat JSON to nested using underscore js

Tags: javascript, node.js, converters

I'm querying some data with a couple of joins and it returns me a flat
`JSON` Object. What I want to do is create a proper hierarchy for
`JSON`. I explored and found out about `Underscore.js` after studying
some more, It looked really complicated to convert it.

Below is what raw query data looks like:

```
"data": [
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 1,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 2,
        "Room_Name": "TV Lounge"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 3,
        "Floor_Name": "1st Floor",
        "Room_Id": 3,
        "Room_Name": "Dining Room"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 2,
        "Building_Address": "G-10 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 4,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 4,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    }
]
```

How I want it to be:

```
 "data": [
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floors": [{
                  "Floor_Id": 1,
                  "Floor_Name: "Ground",
                  "Rooms" : [{
                            "Room_Id": 1,
                            "Room_Name": "Bedroom"},
                            {
                            "Room_Id": 2,
                            "Room_Name": "TV Lounge"}
                            }]
                   },
                  "Floor_Id": 3,
                  "Floor_Name: "1st Floor",
                  "Rooms" : [{
                            "Room_Id": 3,
                            "Room_Name": "Dining Room"
                            }]

    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using underscore.js:

```js
var flatData = {
 "data": [
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 1,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 2,
        "Room_Name": "TV Lounge"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 3,
        "Floor_Name": "1st Floor",
        "Room_Id": 3,
        "Room_Name": "Dining Room"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 2,
        "Building_Address": "G-10 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 4,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 4,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    }
  ]
};

var toNested = function(data) {
  return _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'Building_Id'), function(i) {
    return {
      Building_Id: i[0].Building_Id,
      Building_Address: i[0].Building_Address,
      Floors: _.map(_.groupBy(i, 'Floor_Id'), function(j) {   
        return {
          Floor_Id: j[0].Floor_Id,
          Floor_Name: j[0].Floor_Name,
          Rooms: _.map(j, function(k) {
            return {
              Room_Id: k.Room_Id,
              Room_Name: k.Room_Name
            };
          })
        };
      })
    };
  });
};

var nestedData = {
  "data": toNested(flatData.data)
};

console.log(nestedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help you. But need to improve the code for room level. This is done up to building and floor level

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const flatData = {
  "data": [
    {
      "Building_Id": 1,
      "Building_Address": "i-9 islamabad",
      "Floor_Id": 1,
      "Floor_Name": "Ground",
      "Room_Id": 1,
      "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    },
    {
      "Building_Id": 1,
      "Building_Address": "i-9 islamabad",
      "Floor_Id": 1,
      "Floor_Name": "Ground",
      "Room_Id": 2,
      "Room_Name": "TV Lounge"
    },
    {
      "Building_Id": 1,
      "Building_Address": "i-9 islamabad",
      "Floor_Id": 3,
      "Floor_Name": "1st Floor",
      "Room_Id": 3,
      "Room_Name": "Dining Room"
    },
    {
      "Building_Id": 2,
      "Building_Address": "G-10 Islamabad",
      "Floor_Id": 4,
      "Floor_Name": "Ground",
      "Room_Id": 4,
      "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    }
  ]
}

const buildings = _.groupBy(flatData.data, "Building_Id");
const nestedData = [];
for (var key in buildings) {
  if (buildings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    nestedData.push({
      Building_Id: key,
      Building_Address: buildings[key][0].Building_Address,
      floors: _.map(buildings[key], floor => {
        return {
          Floor_Id: floor.Floor_Id,
          Floor_Name: floor.Floor_Name,
          Room_Id: floor.Room_Id,
          Room_Name: floor.Room_Name
        }
      })
    });
  }
}

console.log(nestedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

use underscorejs

```
var data=[
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 1,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 1,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 2,
        "Room_Name": "TV Lounge"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 1,
        "Building_Address": "i-9 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 3,
        "Floor_Name": "1st Floor",
        "Room_Id": 3,
        "Room_Name": "Dining Room"
    },
    {
        "Building_Id": 2,
        "Building_Address": "G-10 ISLAMABAD",
        "Floor_Id": 4,
        "Floor_Name": "Ground",
        "Room_Id": 4,
        "Room_Name": "Bedroom"
    }
]

var seviyeDesen={
    "groupKey":"Building_Id",
    "keys":["Building_Id","Building_Address"],
    "subKey":"floors",
    "sub":{
        "groupKey":"Floor_Id",
        "keys":["Floor_Id","Floor_Name"],
        "subKey":"rooms",
        "sub":{
            "groupKey":"Room_Id",
            "keys":["Room_Id","Room_Name"]
        }
    }
}

    seviyelendir=function(data,seviyeDesen){        
    if(seviyeDesen.sub){
        return _.map(_.groupBy(data,seviyeDesen.groupKey),function(oge){
            var ustSeviye = _.pick(oge[0],seviyeDesen.keys);                
            ustSeviye[seviyeDesen.subKey]= seviyelendir(oge,seviyeDesen.sub)
            return ustSeviye
        })
    }else{
        return _.map(data,function(oge){return _.pick(oge,seviyeDesen.keys)})
    }
}

console.log(seviyelendir(data,seviyeDesen))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).